Is this a bad tiling job or am I being over the top?
We have a contractor in doing remodeling of bathrooms. We had subway tile for our ensuite and tiler has finished up on Friday but there are a few things that look off to me.

The first thing I noticed was the use of the small cuts of tile in a number of corners. I understand that only a certain number of tiles can fit the width of the wall but would you not just add one cut tile to one end instead of one at each end?


The grouting and lining up of these corners looks bad to me. Should they line look similar the whole way down?


There are areas with uneven tiles in corners. Only in certain areas, large parts of the wall are okay. Can this be foxed easy? Is this expected with these type of tiles?


These corners do not line up as well. Should these be a similar width the whole way down?


Again uneven tiles here. It is much more visible to the eye than the picture.



There are large parts of the wall where there are no problems. But a lot of these small issues around the place. To me it is a sloppy finish to the job. Am I being over the top?
Is there an easy way to fix these?

Perhaps the substrate should have been checked - not many walls are built perfectly square, vertical or straight. Had this with a roof where the holes had been pre-drilled into locations measure on the roof beams. Once mounted on the walls the holes did not line up causing issues with the pipe for the solar water heating and air locks.

Agree with Solar Mike.  Most all of the issues you pointed out are magnified 4X because of the dark grout.  A light grout and these things are not noticed.  Generally I think it looks like an average job, not particularly sloppy.  The small tile at each end are the result of the usual layout of starting at the center.  If you wanted something different , You should have indicated that before the job was started.

If they didn't start with the center then some customers would complain about the tiles on left and right not matching. No perfect solution, especially with large tiles. As far as the other things did the contractor make the walls or were they working with existing drywall?

@RMDman the contractor mentioned starting from the center as well. Didn't specify here. This is a source of annoyance as well. Hadn't had a chance to have a proper chat about these finer details. It was not brought up with us and a bit of naivety on our part not to get into these details. Funny enough we were going to go with black but changed our mind and we're going with white. The contractor talked us into the dark grey.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact yeah in my head it makes perfect sense to his the small cuts of tile in the other corner but again it wasn't something that was discussed. Contractor stripped tile that was there and remade the walls around the shower area. The rest around the sink/toilet were there already. House is only 2 years old. Would using existing wall cause a problem?

@SolarMike is there anything that can be done before the tiling starts that can address issues with the substrate?

It is only that using existing walls (which, to be honest, most people will do unless they are totally gutting the bathroom for a major renovation or due to a fire) are often not quite straight/plumb consistently. If, for example, two pieces of drywall are at a bit of an angle to each other (likely due to poor original installation) then tiling over it will carry through the imperfections. And it could be that the previous tile job was "better" or it could be that the size of the tiles made it harder to notice the problems.

Does seem to be a lot of lippage here—no way to tell from my chair whether it's a fault of the installer, or the tile selected...

There is no easy fix to any of this. The tiles in the "problem" areas would have to be broken out and new ones put in. As far as starting in the center, the whole wall would have to be redone.  The corners might be able to be evened out with a small bead of black caulk. Usually, corners are caulked and not grouted so installing caulk would even out those lines. I would consider this an average job.

Thanks. We have another bathroom to be tiled as well. Is it worth our time getting them to try fix some of the problem tiles first? Would it take long? Redoing a whole wall might be pushing it but I am not sure where we stand. Wouldn't have huge experience dealing with these things.

You could ask him about the caulking issue but that's about it if things weren't hashed out ahead of time. Once you start adjusting a tile, if will affect the ones around it, then you've got to adjust them. Like I said, no easy fix and it's an average job. Some of this should have been pointed out to him before the job was completed.  live and learn for the next bathroom.
